# php mysql get total price

Tags: php, mysql, function

Im coding a shopping cart but I got a problem with the total price.

This is the function I try to code:

```
function get_total_price(){
    $result=mysql_query("SELECT SUM(price) FROM db.cart WHERE user_id='".mysql_real_escape_string($_SESSION['user_id'])."'") or die();
    return $result;
  }
```

but as result I get

> Resource id #10

Hope someone can help. First ive started coding without functions but now I want to learn how to create php funcitons etc.

Comment: Any php/mysql tutorial would cover this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So first [mysql_query](https://www.php.net/mysql_query) is depreciated, you should be looking at [mysqli_query](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php) instead.  But it's actually working the correct way, when the SQL is execute you get a link identifier back if the query is successful. You then need to open that using for example [mysql_fetch_array](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php) so the final script would be:

```
function get_total_price(){
    $result=mysql_query("SELECT SUM(price) FROM db.cart WHERE user_id='".
      mysql_real_escape_string($_SESSION['user_id'])."'") or die();
    $row= mysql_fetch_array($result);
    mysql_free_result($result);//Be a good citizen and release the memory
    return $row[0];//The actual sum
  }
```

Or with the newer library:

```
//mysqli is a link to the database
function get_total_price($mysqli){
    $result=$mysqli->query("SELECT SUM(price) FROM db.cart WHERE user_id='".
      $mysqli->real_escape_string($_SESSION['user_id'])."'");
    if (!$result) die();//This could be more instructive
    $row=$result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_NUM);
    $result->free();
    return $row[0];//The actual sum
  }
```

Comment: Just the way he wrote it dude... if someone changes the query they'll need to change the code.  It would have to be named if you wanted to use an associated array download. (Although you're not suggesting a solution?!)

Comment: K, I can find your edit request, someone in the community rejected it (*shrug* no reason is given, it wasn't me).  If someone rewrote the SQL to rename the named parameter... you'd have to change *your* code too ;)

Comment: Ok i've edited it again.. "Thanks for your edit!
This edit will be visible only to you until it is peer reviewed." and i'am removing mine comments..

Answer (score 1):

You are using a deprecated version of `mysql_*` function. See http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php or PDO: http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php.

By the way now you have to fetch your array with: `mysql_fetch_array()` function.

Example:

```
while ( $row = mysql_fetch_array($result) )
{
print_r($row);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your query does not return the value itself, but a resource containing the value. so u should try to iterate through the resource like:

```
$resource = mysql_query("SELECT SUM(price) FROM db.cart WHERE user_id='".mysql_real_escape_string($_SESSION['user_id'])."'") or die();
        if($resource){
            while($data = mysql_fetch_array($resource)){
                // iterating
            }
        }
```